# Get PeoplePicker value Edit Form

Tags: javascript, office-365, people-picker

I want to get the Name of the User in the people picker Field of the Edit form.

My Javascript is as below :

`$("#Superior").html(ArrayRetrieved.ImmediateSuperior.Id);`
The result is the below

[image]

Then in the Front End i have this result :

[image]

it's a non modified value even when i

I make:

```
$("#Superior").html(ArrayRetrieved.ImmediateSuperior.Title);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to do that, for one User, i found this solution

```
// RETRIEVE ONE USER
var GetOneUser = function (UserIDToUse) {
if (UserIDToUse != null) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/GetUserById(" + UserIDToUse + ")",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                dfd.resolve(data.d);
            },
            error: function () {
                dfd.reject(args.get_message());
            }
        });
    });
    return dfd.promise();
} else {
    return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
}
};
```

and then we call it in the Retrieve Function like that  :

> ```
>            GetOneUser(ArrayRetrieved.ImmediateSuperior.Id).done(function (user) {
>                 $("#Superior").spPeoplePicker(false, user);
>             });
> ```

But i'm looking now for the multiUsers function!
If you can help me, or if i find the solution, i will post it again :)

Answer (score 0):

So, for multiUsers this is the solution : So just in the retrieve function we add this code :

```
if (ArrayRetrieved.EmployeesReportingToThisUser.results.length != 0 && ArrayRetrieved.EmployeesReportingToThisUser != null) {
      for (var j = 0; j < ArrayRetrieved.EmployeesReportingToThisUser.results.length; j++) {
           GetUser(ArrayRetrieved.EmployeesReportingToThisUser.results[j].Id).done(function () {
           $("#Employees").spPeoplePicker(true, ArrayRetrieved.EmployeesReportingToThisUser.results);
           });
       }
 }
```